# How to save image through webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Suppose I'm using a URL in webview http://demo.io and this URL has a button of camera and when I click on that camera button then my URL became http://demo.io/captureImage. Then I have an issue when I check the url of webview then it shows only http://demo.io not showing http://demo.io/captureImage so how I can get this URL in Android. Because this URL has an image and I wanna save this image. When this URL (http://demo.io/captureImage) runs on chrome and I capture the image then captured image downloaded but in Android webview image after capturing not downloading. Please suggest me appropriate answer or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a download listner to webivew and download the image from the url as shown below

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your issue correctly,

First you have to reset `WebView` with new url. Try below to do this,

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    UrActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://demo.io/captureImage");
   }});
```

Second is to download image you can use `setDownloadListener(...)` as suggested by @Hasif Seyd